# Open source ПО на C++ для скачивания видео/аудио с youtube

Tags: видео, opensource, c++, mp3

Существуют ли проекты по скачиванию видео или аудио с youtube с открытым исходным кодом на C++? Я нашёл [utube2mp3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/utube2mp3/), но эта прога не работает. Наверное потому, что youtube изменил формат страниц с видео, а прогу не обновили. Есть всем известный работающий скрипт на python. Но хотелось бы на C++ найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список на [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=download+youtube&fq%5B%5D=trove%3A165)